# Mail markup: google tester- ok, my server- bad

Tags: gmail, schema, jsonp, sendmail

I have the problem with google mail markup 
https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/overview#gmail_actions

I tried Json-Ld and Microdata. But i have nothing. When i try to send me mail from google tester https://script.google.com/ - everything is ok and i get the letter with quick button. But when i send the same letter from my server- i get letter without quick button. At my server i tryed to change mail's charset, encoding, i tryed to use php function mail and PHPmailer script (yii)- the result is the same.
What should i see the next

Answer (score 1):

Thank everybody for answers. lol

But i found that i should add me to wite list at google here
https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google
Writers from google didn't mention about it at first part of instruction